# Psycopg2 Error MissingModuleSource but the module is installed

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect to PostgresSql in python using psycopg2. I ran the following in my VS-Code and Mac terminal:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

It says that the requirement is already satisfied. Yet, when I go to import psycopg2 I get the following error:

```
Import "psycopg2" could not be resolved from source Pylance(reportMissingModuleSource) [1,8]
```

Comment: What is "it"? What is your environment?

Answer (score 0):

Now I noticed that this message is from your VS Code IDE and not from the Python interpreter.

You probably misconfigured your IDE and it is not using the same interpreter, you are installing the Psycopg2 in.

There is a [bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1739), which may help you debug your IDE.